# How to use Keychain in iPhone?

Tags: ios, cordova, keychain

I am working on an iPhone/iOS app using phonegap and I am new to this iOS/iPhone environment. It has a login page with two text fields "email" & "Password".Now i want to save email. i.e When I logged out it should remember the email address so it doesn't have to be input again.

I went through many links and found that I can implement this functionality using Keychain.
I found few examples but those are in native c.

Since am using phonegap, can anyone explain me how to implement keychain in phonegap.
And do I have to include any plugins for that?

Comment: https://github.com/shazron/KeychainPlugin and/or https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/161

Comment: @gro I have referred these two links. According to github it says we have to add <gap:plugin name="com.shazron.cordova.plugin.keychainutil" version="1.0.0" /> Can I directly add it to config.xml? No need to download any plugin?

Comment: there are a lot of tutorials on implementing plugins for cordova/phonegap. Once implemented, you can use the the plugin's javascript getForKey() and setForKey() methods.

Comment: per link...Manually importing the plugin is not supported anymore, please use Plugman or the Cordova CLI tool.  (downloads and installs plugin)